# WebGL flickering shader when setting varying value in Firefox

Tags: glsl, webgl

I'm following a basic tutorial learning about WebGL (https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-fundamentals.html). Currently I'm just drawing a square (2 triangles) to the screen.

I tried to modify the basic vertex shader to pass the clipspace XY coordinates to the fragment shader, but when I write it the following way it causes flickering in Firefox

Vertex Shader

```
attribute vec2 a_position;

uniform vec2 u_resolution;

varying vec2 uv;

void main(){
    vec2 pixelPos = a_position.xy / u_resolution;
    pixelPos *= 2.0;
    pixelPos -= 1.0;

    uv = pixelPos;

    gl_Position = vec4(pixelPos, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 uv;

void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(uv, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

The weird part is, if I modify the vertex shader to instead use `uv = (pixelPos + 1.0) / 2.0;` the flickering stops. Logically I don't see what the difference would be (no divide by zero errors or anything) so I'm not sure what's causing it.

Seems to work fine in Chrome though

Comment: [tag:webgl] != [tag:opengl]

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with your shaders, so it's possible you've found some kind of browser or graphics driver bug. If you can make a simple reproducer you may want to report it to mozilla.

Comment: Ok, I'll make a JSFiddle or something and submit it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`uv = (pixelPos * 2.0) - 1.0` is not the same as `uv = (pixelPos + 1.0) / 2.0;`

```
vec2 pixelPos = a_position.xy / u_resolution; // in the range [0 to 1]
pixelPos *= 2.0;                              // in the range [0 to 2]
pixelPos -= 1.0;                              // in the range [-1 to 1]
uv = pixelPos;
```

```
vec2 pixelPos = a_position.xy / u_resolution; // in the range [0 to 1]
pixelPos += 1.0;                              // in the range [0 to 2]
pixelPos /= 2.0;                              // in the range [0 to 1]
uv = pixelPos;
```

The flickering may be caused by setting gl_FragColor's red and green values to negative numbers. They should be clamped to zero but the way clamping is handled in FF vs Chrome might cause the discrepancy.

Comment: Definitely some kind of weird precision issue. Setting it to `uv = pixelPos - 0.0001;` fixes the flickering even without getting rid of negative values. I'm just going to submit a big report to FF as it's looking like a problem on their end